# Linker segmentation fault while compiling arduino in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, arduino

I am trying to build arduino code in Eclipse. I was able to build  ArduinoCore fine. But while building the application, I am getting a segmentation fault during the linking.

```
Building target: TestAVR.elf
Invoking: AVR C++ Linker
avr-gcc –cref -s -Os -o”TestAVR.elf” ./src/main.o -lArduinoCore -lm -Wl,-Map,TestAVR.map,–cref -mrelax -Wl,–gc-sections -L/home/harsh/workspace/avr/ArduinoCore/Release -mmcu=atmega328p
collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
make: *** [TestAVR.elf] Error 1
Binutils is the latest version
```

All the tools seem to be the latest. Is the library not built properly or it is the issue with the linker?

Comment: If your linker segfaults. it is a bug in the linker. A correct program doesn't segfault.

Comment: How can I solve this?

Comment: File a bug report and hope that they fix it. Until then, either change your code st it does not trigger the bug or use other tools.

Comment: I am sorry, I followed a tutorial which mentioned the linker command as avr-gcc –cref -s -Os -o”TestAVR.elf” ./src/main.o -lArduinoCore -lm -Wl,-Map,TestAVR.map,–cref -mrelax -Wl,–gc-sections -L/home/harsh/workspace/avr/ArduinoCore/Release -mmcu=atmega328p

I changed that to avr-g++ and it works fine

Comment: Oops, I missed that. The linker should still not segfault, but I guess it not working with the wrong language is pretty excusable.

Comment: how do I close this topic?

Comment: This does not look OT to me (problem is shown in your question), so you can just write an answer yourself and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the linker command from

```
avr-gcc –cref -s -Os -o”TestAVR.elf” ./src/main.o -lArduinoCore -lm -Wl,-Map,TestAVR.map,–cref -mrelax -Wl,–gc-sections -L/workspace/avr/ArduinoCore/Release -mmcu=atmega328p
```

to

```
avr-g++
```

and it works fine.